# Combining two existing models in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

This is a question from an MVC dump:

You are designing an MVC web application. 
The view must be as simple as possible for designers who do not have a technical background. 
You need to combine two existing models to meet the requirement. 
Which component of the MVC framework should you use?

```
A.    View 
B.    View Model 
C.    Controller 
D.    Model
```

Answer: D

Is this correct ? As per my understanding we should use a ViewModel .

Answer (score 0):

Well if you see, there is nothing tangible when we talk of `ViewModel`, rather the term is used more to hint about the the `Model` to which the `View` is bind. Generally when we come across a situation where our `View` requires more than single `Model`, we put a wrapper class around it and call it `ViewModel`
Anyways your business/domain entities should be different from `Model` or `ViewModel` for that matter.

Now to simply answer your question, as you need multiple `Models` for your `View`, you should have a wrapper class around it and it is absolutely fair to call it `ViewModel`, so in a sense, you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, a *view models* is a *model* which is designed to match the needs of the View. That means: If you "combine" to *model* "to meet the requirements", you will have a *view models*.

What I do in my MVC Projects: I work with *models* in the C# code and pass *view models* to the views to work with it inside the views.

Answer (score 0):

I think for a developer using MVC who is developing as part of a team of other experienced MVC developers then you are correct, you should use a ViewModel to separate out the display logic from the domain model or the database model (dependant on your application architecture).

However, I think the key part to this question is "The view must be as simple as possible for designers who do not have a technical background."

Therefore, I imagine that the question is suggesting that you should do the simplist thing possible for people with less experience and just create or use existing models directly in the view.

However, the confusing part of the question is that it asks you what would you use to combine two existing models (ie. what sort of wrapper class would you use). This wrapper class could be created alongside the other domain/database models in which case you may call it a model.  Or you may create a wrapper class in the UI MVC project which combines the two existing models and call this a view model.  As the question asks "which component would you use of the MVC framework" (i.e the UI layer) then I would expect that the wrapper class would be referred to as a view model.  But the question also mentions "the MVC framework"; MVC standing for Model, View, Controller so it may be that you think it is expecting you refer the wrapper class as the model.

At the end of the day, IMHO the question is vague and both answers could be considered correct.  Regardless, the wrapper class you create may look exactly the same whether you call it a model or a view model.

Comment: This is a question form 70 486 Microsoft Certification

Answer (score 0):

This is old but the correct answer is ViewModel, regarding to the question is: "You need to combine two existing models to meet the requirement." Then if you choice the answer "Model", this is not correct. It must be View Model combined

B) is correct answer

Best,